# partition sequence by barriers of indices

Tags: r, arrays, partition

Given a sequence `s <- 10:1`, is there any elegant function in `base R` that allows you to set barriers for the indices of `s` to partition `s`?

For example, if `barriers <- c(3,7)`, which means the separation occurs at the 3rd and 7th position in `s`, such that the desired output should be a list of partitions, like

```
> list(10:8,7:4,3:1)
[[1]]
[1] 10  9  8

[[2]]
[1] 7 6 5 4

[[3]]
[1] 3 2 1
```

Note that, if `barriers <- c(3,10)`, since nothing left for the partition beyond barrier at 10th position, hence the desired output should be as

```
> list(10:8,7:1)
[[1]]
[1] 10  9  8

[[2]]
[1] 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

**Solution**:  thanks for the clues provided by @RonakShah and @GKi

```
split(s, findInterval(seq_along(s), barriers, left.open = TRUE))
```

Comment: You can use `split(s, findInterval(s, barriers + 1))` but I don't understand your 2nd condition.

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks for the answer! The 2nd condition is that, the last barrier, i.e., `10` in `barrier <- c(3,10)`, is at the last position of the sequence, such that there will be only 2 partitions of `s` with 10 entries.

Comment: @RonakShah  I guess `split(s, findInterval(seq_along(s), barriers+1))` is the thing I exactly need to keep the same order of `s`. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` and `findInterval` like:

```
s <- 10:1
barriers <- c(3,7)
split(s, findInterval(seq_along(s), barriers, left.open = TRUE))
#$`0`
#[1] 10  9  8
#
#$`1`
#[1] 7 6 5 4
#
#$`2`
#[1] 3 2 1

barriers <- c(3,10)
split(s, findInterval(seq_along(s), barriers, left.open = TRUE))
#$`0`
#[1] 10  9  8
#
#$`1`
#[1] 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess `split(s, findInterval(seq_along(s), barriers+1))` is the thing I exactly need to keep the same order of `s`.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I think its more like `split(s, findInterval(s, barriers, left.open = TRUE))`

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Or maybe the solution with `-`?

Comment: I think `split(s, findInterval(seq_along(s), barriers, left.open = TRUE))` works well for my objective, since the barriers are for indices rather than `s`, so the approach with `-` may be not applicable for my other general cases. For instance, `barrier <- c(3,10)` cannot achieve the desired output

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Oh yes, you are asking for *indices*! Sorry for overlooking this.